# MVC Controller returning JSON but not binding in Knockout

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am trying a simple binding using JsonResult from MVC Controller.  The json comes back but the bindings in knockout observable array does work.  Below is my code.

If I put the json result directly to the observable it works.  I am not sure what I am missing here.

**Knockout Code**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping.js"></script>

var viewModel;
vmListModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.Products = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.GetData = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("product", "employees")',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            success: function (rs) {
                console.log(rs);  //--> the data returns like this { Id: '1001', Name: 'xavier' }
                //self.Products({ Id: '1001', Name: 'xavier' });  // if I put this it binds
                ko.mapping.fromJS(rs, {}, self.Products);
                //self.Products(ko.mapping.fromJS(rs));
            }
        });
    }


};


$(document).ready(function () {
    viewModel = new vmListModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#products1')[0]);
    viewModel.GetData();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="products1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach:Products">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text:Id">
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text:Name">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Controller code**

```
  public JsonResult Product()
    {
        string variablename = "{Id:'1001',Name:'xavier'}";
        return Json(variablename, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Error**

Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return Id }"
Message: Id is not defined

Comment: Can you make the changes as per your data bind logic  http://jsfiddle.net/zNkhR/138/ ? I have made a  basic setup which works.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but this data come from the controller.  Is there something I need to on the controller?

Comment: from the comments i just copied the structure to a variable and initialized the view model. Verify what you are getting the same structure from the action method.

Comment: in the console.log I am getting this ``{Id:'1001',Name:'xavier'}`` and if I check in the observable I am getting this ``viewModel.Products()
"{Id:'1001',Name:'xavier'}"``

Comment: do you have reference to knockout.mapping.js ?

Comment: Yes I do, I updated my code

Comment: Can you put   <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data.Products, null, 2)"></pre> before the start of table and see what it contains?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84252/discussion-between-adrian-and-rohith-nair).

Comment: Try `ko.mapping.fromJS(JSON.parse(rs), {}, self.Products);`. You get back string from the ajax call, you need to convert it to object before you can call fomJS with it.

Comment: @artm that does not work - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

Comment: That means your json string is not in the correct format, see http://jsfiddle.net/xqvmwp9x/

Comment: @artm my data comes like this from the controller  { Id: '1001', Name: 'xavier' } so I think the [] is missing not sure how to get it with the []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are passing data of type `string` from controller and trying to convert using `mapping` plugin which is wrong in all sorts

**FIX:** Build a array and pass it . so mapping plugin will convert everything to observable's and you can have successful 2-way binding intact .

**Controller :**

```
var data = new[] { new { Id = "1001", Name = "Nancy" }, new { Id = "1002", Name = "bunny" } };
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Hope that helps